# Read and Analyze Data on another webpage and insert onto mine

Tags: java, html, matlab, web-scraping

Im trying to make a simple webpage which obtains football league table data

http://www.skysports.com/football/league/0,19540,11660,00.html

For example i want to read in the points column and divide it by the number of games played to get an average points per game column that i will print onto my webpage.

How can i do this online?

Im quite experienced at doing this with offline programmes such as C/Matlab but i dont know where to start with it online.

Thanks

Comment: Perl is a great tool for webscraping and parsing html or xml. I have done exactly what you want to do for many many web sites and all done with perl using LWP::Simple package and basic regexp pattern matching

Comment: If we are recommending other languages, then Python and Ruby each have many excellent packages for just this purpose :)

Comment: Sorry, didnt see the java tag. Thought he was looking for general webscraping options.

Comment: Badly tagged question? never heard of Matlab used for scraping..

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't suggest to do it client side (on browser). It will be easier to scrap on server side (using java for example) following the steps:

1. Grab the content of the webpage (skysports)
2. Use existing html markup with regex to locate the desired content part.
3. Strip/split html markup with regex to get records (tr) and fields (td).
4. Cast values and do your math.
5. Use results to generate your version of html or json or whatever.
6. Serve the generated content to your client.

In general scrapping is easy but not guaranteed for tomorrow as source html markup may change at any time (and without warning).

I can provide a basic sample in C# if you want. (Sorry I haven't "java" since 1997).

Answer (score 0):

You use [jQuery.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)  like this:

```
$.get('http://www.skysports.com/football/league/0,19540,11660,00.html', function(data) {
//do the parsing here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several programing languages capable of getting at this information, **PHP** would be the classic method using **curl** or **file_get_contents** and regex parsing to extract the bits you want. You could  do it with **Yahoo Pipes** as well if your web host does not allow remote URL retrieval.

If none of the Java brigade come back with something better contact me and I'll do some rough code for you in PHP.